# No way to use TSQL Output with normal foreign key constraints?

Tags: t-sql

The following snippet fails with error:

> The target table 'dbo.forn' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found reference constraint 'FK_forn_prim'."

I can only use output by disabling foreign key constraints?  How can this be done?

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.forn') IS NOT NULL
begin
    alter table dbo.forn drop constraint FK_forn_prim
    DROP TABLE dbo.forn;
end
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.prim') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.prim;
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.prim (c1 int PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE dbo.forn (c1 int CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim FOREIGN KEY (c1) REFERENCES dbo.prim(c1));
go

INSERT INTO dbo.prim
    OUTPUT inserted.c1 INTO dbo.forn
SELECT 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

> There is no guarantee that the order in which the changes are applied to the table and the order in which the rows are inserted into the output table or table variable will correspond.

Based on this there are a number of restrictions, among which is the one you ran into above, but if all you want is to record the inserted value in a second table I don't see why you would need the foreign key relationship you define above.

If you do need the foreign key relationship you could accomplish the same thing by using a trigger like this.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.forn') IS NOT NULL
begin
    alter table dbo.forn drop constraint FK_forn_prim
    DROP TABLE dbo.forn;
end
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.prim') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.prim;
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.prim (c1 int PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE dbo.forn (c1 int CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim FOREIGN KEY (c1) REFERENCES dbo.prim(c1));
go

CREATE TRIGGER InsertRecord
   ON  dbo.Prim
   AFTER Insert
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Insert into dbo.forn Select * from inserted;
END
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.prim SELECT 1;
```

Comment: Well, that snippet was there just to illustrate the problem; I have normal tables, and the trigger won't work.  I'll have to disable constraints.

Answer (score 16):

Normally you output to a table variable or temp table, then use that to insert to the final table.

Comment: Could you add an example?

Answer (score 3):

You're correct, output statements won't work on tables under foreign key constraints.

Another option would be to temporarily disable the constraints while you insert the data.  Though this shouldn't be the norm, it works well for one time loads of data.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.forn
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.prim
    OUTPUT inserted.c1 INTO dbo.forn
SELECT 1;

ALTER TABLE dbo.forn
CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does indicate that the output table may not participate in foreign key constraints (or check constraints, nor may it have enabled triggers defined on it--but those cases aren't considered here).  The Msg 332 error is the manifestation of that.

(***THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED.*** See update below)

However, I have found that this limitation is subverted if the foreign key constraint is disabled and re-enabled with `NOCHECK/CHECK` *even after the constraint is re-enabled*.  In other words: one disable-enable cycle is enough to make the FK constraint "invisible" to the output-into-foreign-key-constraint prohibition.  Note the modification below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.forn') IS NOT NULL
begin
    alter table dbo.forn drop constraint FK_forn_prim
    DROP TABLE dbo.forn;
end
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.prim') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.prim;
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.prim (c1 int PRIMARY KEY);
-- note change here:
CREATE TABLE dbo.forn (c1 int );
alter TABLE dbo.forn with nocheck add CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim FOREIGN KEY (c1)     REFERENCES dbo.prim(c1);
alter TABLE dbo.forn check CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim ;
-- end change
go

INSERT INTO dbo.prim
    OUTPUT inserted.c1 INTO dbo.forn
select 1;
```

The following fails (constraint violation) so you know the DRI is still working:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.prim
    OUTPUT inserted.c1 + 1 INTO dbo.forn
select 2;
```

Given the prohibition in the docs, I grant this seems dubious.  I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087837/why-does-this-t-sql-output-into-with-foreign-key-hack-work) pending on this point, though it hasn't been well-received.

### UPDATE

The previously mentioned question was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35724885/85269), and the new information invalidates this answer.  Leaving this up as a warning to others, in case they stumble upon this seemingly fortuitous hole.

The upshot is: `alter TABLE dbo.forn check CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim ;` reenables the constraint but leaves it in an "untrusted" state, so it cannot be fully utilized by the SQL engine for index optimization and such.  It is not recommended.  The correct way to reenable is

```
alter table dbo.forn with check check CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim;
```

Comment: Very interesting even though the approach may not be recommended.

Comment: It certainly isn't. Your comment reminded me of this and that I now know better.  Hopefully this hasn't mislead many.

Comment: Dropping/  reenabling foreign keys is massive. Foreign keys are used by query optimiser - disabling them removes them from query plan - recompiles for related queries... reenabling will trigger another recompile... and corruption may have occurred while the check was down - via insert or update by any other user.

Answer (score 0):

Use insert into table variable 
DECLARE @HISTORY_EXTENSION TABLE
(
HISTORY_ID INT NOT NULL,
NUMBER NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

-- Move From
INSERT INTO [dbo].[HISTORY]
([CODE]
,[STAMP]
)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, DATE
INTO @HISTORY_EXTENSION (
[HISTORY_ID]
,[NUMBER]
)
SELECT
1,
DATE
FROM TRANSACTION
WHERE DATE = '2021-05-20'

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Genre VARCHAR(10) = 'DIY'
CREATE TABLE BOOK (BookID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Title VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE BookInfo (BookInfoID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Book INT REFERENCES Book(BookID), Genre VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE #NewBook (BookID INT, Genre VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO BOOK (Title)
OUTPUT INSERTED.BookID, @Genre 
INTO #NewBook(BookID, Genre)
VALUES ('Like so!')

INSERT INTO BookInfo (Book, Genre)
SELECT BookId, Genre
FROM #NewBook

DROP TABLE #NewBook

SELECT * FROM Book
SELECT * FROM BookInfo

DROP TABLE Book
DROP TABLE BookInfo
```