# Why does this T-SQL OUTPUT INTO with FOREIGN KEY hack work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

The base example is lifted from [No way to use TSQL Output with normal foreign key constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344891/no-way-to-use-tsql-output-with-normal-foreign-key-constraints/11830522#11830522); his code fails as expected.  But if the way the constraint is defined in the example is modified as below, defining the FK constraint `WITH NOCHECK` and then `CHECK`ing it, the OUTPUT INTO will run unimpeded.

This seems to contradict the [OUTPUT clause docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).  Specifically:

> output_table [the table receiving the INTO] cannot:
>
> •Have enabled triggers defined on it.
>
> •*Participate on either side of a FOREIGN KEY constraint* [emphasis added].
>
> •Have CHECK constraints or enabled rules.

From a relational perspective the below *could* work, but this action is supposed to be specifically precluded.  If the FK is defined as a straight "WITH CHECK" (the default) it fails as expected.  If it is defined "WITH NOCHECK" and then enabled with a "CHECK CONSTRAINT" it, well, fails to fail.

It would be awesome if this was a known, supported feature.  Or did I just find a bug in SQL that's persisted since at least SQL 2008 (I tested with 2008 and 2014)? Why does this work? Why shouldn't it? What am I risking by using it?

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.forn') IS NOT NULL
begin
    alter table dbo.forn drop constraint FK_forn_prim
    DROP TABLE dbo.forn;
end
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.prim') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.prim;
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.prim (c1 int PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE dbo.forn (c1 int );
alter table dbo.forn with nocheck add CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim FOREIGN KEY (c1) REFERENCES dbo.prim(c1);
alter table dbo.forn check CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim ;
go

-- does in fact fail with foreign key constraint violation
insert dbo.forn values (2);

-- works!!
INSERT INTO dbo.prim
    OUTPUT inserted.c1 INTO dbo.forn
SELECT 1;
```

Comment: whats wrong with your insert? first into prim and afterwards into forn or do i miss something?

Comment: A: updated question.

Comment: I think because it is an implicit transaction and constraint checking is at the  end of the  transaction.  Try OUTPUT inserted.c1 + 100 INTO dbo.forn

Comment: @Blam: that would of course fail with a constraint violation, just as `insert prim values(1); insert forn values(101);` would fail.  It doesn't answer the question of why a scenario specifically precluded by the docs that does fail with one form of code, fails to fail with seemingly equivalent code.

Comment: Yes it does explain why it fails to fail.  1 is inserted into both tables and THEN the constraint is evaluated.   Did you vote me down?  -1

Comment: @Blam: I did indeed, nothing personal, just doesn't answer the question: if the output table *may not participate in either side of a foreign key constraint* (see doc) then it shouldn't work either way.  Please follow the first link in my question, cut and paste the original code and note the failure and the error message.  The difference is in the constraint definition, which appears to subvert this limitation.  The question is, is the error in SQL or in the documentation?

Comment: But it is NOT an error in SQL.  The insert happens.  If you do a select the 1 is in both tables.  It does answer the question - it works because it is an implicit transaction and the fk contraint is enforced at the end.  You asked why it works and I explained it.  Your assertion that it is a BUG is without merit.  It performed the insert and reports row inserted - that is not a bug.  If it did not perform the insert and failed to throw an error then that would be a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreign key is still not trusted by the system after the with check statement. This is because the default for existing constraints is WITH NOCHECK, so you're effectively running:

```
    alter table dbo.forn with nocheck check CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim;
```

Correct statement to re-enable is:

```
    alter table dbo.forn with check check CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim;
```

The nested insert will fail again after running that. Not recommended to leave the FK untrusted as SQL will not consider it for many operations.

You can check for untrusted FK's in system view sys.foreign_keys, is_not_trusted field.

More here: https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2007/03/can-you-trust-your-constraints/

Comment: Wow, thank you for digging up this old "-1" question and reading closely enough to give a good answer!  "untrusted constraints..." I'm achamed for now knowing about these after 15 years of working with MS SQL! Do you know of any MSDN documentation that connects the dots between this limitation of the `OUTPUT` clause and its behavior with un/trusted constraints?

Comment: Also, hate to beg but since the question made sense and I was just ignorant and not going insane, please upvote it!  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Can't find any documentation about OUTPUT INTO working with untrusted constraints. Although the ALTER TABLE page is a bit clearer on the CHECK CHECK syntax than it used to be! Have added a comment to MSDN's OUTPUT clause page.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement that outputs the created value into the second table works because you are going the opposite direction of your foreign key constraint.  The inner statement is dependent upon the outer statement so it will be executed after the record gets created in the other table.

SQL Server will only check this foreign key when records dbo.forn are created or updated.  As long as you insert into dbo.prim before dbo.forn your code will execute.

Works:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.prim
    OUTPUT inserted.c1 INTO dbo.forn
```

Fails:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.forn
    OUTPUT inserted.c1 INTO dbo.prim
```

---

***Edit:***

Microsoft probably choose to shortcut documenting what is probably a fairly complex scenario by saying you should not expect it to work.  I would bet that based on the specifics listed for OUTPUT [INTO] with UPDATE and DELETE statements, a similar attempt with UPDATE or DELETE would fail.

{INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE} * {Types of Constraints} * {Types of Columns} * {Types of triggers} * {Whatever Else I Missed} turns into an amazingly large number of combinations to document.

As usual, empirical evidence wins, your scenario is possible.

Comment: Re: Edit: haven't tested DELETE yet, but I initially saw this difference in the UPDATE scenario.  The variable here is between what I thought was equivalent code: defining an FK `WITH CHECK` (default) or `WITH NOCHECK` and then enabling with `CHECK CONSTRAINT`.  Empirical doesn't help if MS "closes the loophole" in a future version and the code breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure the answer is that is an implicit transaction and constraint checking is at the end of the transaction

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.forn') IS NOT NULL
begin
    alter table dbo.forn drop constraint FK_forn_prim
    DROP TABLE dbo.forn;
end
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.prim') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.prim;
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.prim (c1 int PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE dbo.forn (c1 int );
alter table dbo.forn with nocheck add CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim FOREIGN KEY (c1) REFERENCES dbo.prim(c1);
alter table dbo.forn check CONSTRAINT FK_forn_prim ;
go

-- does in fact fail with foreign key constraint violation
insert dbo.forn values (1);

-- works!!
INSERT INTO dbo.prim
    OUTPUT inserted.c1 INTO dbo.forn
SELECT 2;

-- does in fact fail with foreign key constraint violation
INSERT INTO dbo.prim
    OUTPUT inserted.c1 + 1 INTO dbo.forn
SELECT 5;

select * from dbo.prim;  -- 2 insert - it really did work   
select * from dbo.forn;  -- 2 insert - it really did work
```

Comment: See comment response on question above.

Comment: What part of the constraint is enforced after the implicit transaction is not clear?