# SCOPE_IDENTITY() is returning NULL instead of expected value

Tags: python, sql-server, scope-identity

With Python and SQL Server, I am inserting a row into table. Post record insertion, I am using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get latest ID for inserted record. Instead of receiving expected ID, the function is returning `NULL`. Please can anyone help me getting latest ID for inserted record.

Python code:

```
InsertFileQuery = """
BEGIN
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [MYDB].[dbo].[TABLE]([A] ,[B],[C] ,[D] ,[E] ,[F])
                  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
   END
END
                 """

values = (A, B, C, D, E, F)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(InsertFileQuery, values)

cursor.execute("select SCOPE_IDENTITY()")
row = cursor.fetchone()
seed_id = row[0]
print(row)       #Null Value
print(seed_id)   #Null Value
```

Comment: From [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL) - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types): *"SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return the last identity values that are generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns values inserted only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope."*. Getting the value in a separate session/scope ***willl*** return `NULL`; as you're seeing here.

Comment: Any idea, How do I incorporate SCOPE_IDENTITY() in above query(same transaction) and store it in variable? - Which can be used for future operations.

Comment: Be cautious using @@IDENTITY, though, the devil is in the details. As the documentation says, "@@IDENTITY return the last identity values that are generated in any table in the current session," which means that if your primary table has triggers on it that insert into other tables (e.g.: for logging/auditing purposes) you'll likely get identity values for the trigger-related tables.

Comment: I am no knowledge of Python I'm afraid, but one would **assume** it can handle an `INSERT` and `SELECT` statement in the same statement. Also, why do you have 2 `BEGIN` and `END` clauses in your SQL? They're completely redundant.

Comment: Maybe [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can be handy here?

Comment: @stickybit: I am not completely sure about  OUTPUT as my both tables are connected using private and foreign key relationship. Using OUTPUT gave me some foreign key constraints. Hence I moved to this approach.

Comment: `OUTPUT` has no effect on the constraints... That implies your `OUTPUT` statement was wrong.

Comment: @Larnu: Thanks for clarification.I referred this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344891/no-way-to-use-tsql-output-with-normal-foreign-key-constraints. Let me try inserting rows into two related tables using OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have anywhere to test it right now but it looks to me like this should work:

```
InsertFileQuery = """
    INSERT INTO [MYDB].[dbo].[TABLE]([A] ,[B],[C] ,[D] ,[E] ,[F])
                  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                 """

values = (A, B, C, D, E, F)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(InsertFileQuery, values)

row = cursor.fetchone()
seed_id = row[0]
print(row)       #Null Value
print(seed_id)   #Null Value
```